# Why is .NET class System.String now in three different assemblies, according to MSDN?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I just recently discovered on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2) that e.g. class `System.String` of the .NET framework now lives in three different assemblies, namely `System.Runtime.dll`, `mscorlib.dll` and also `netstandard.dll`.

Before, this class existed only in the assembly `mscorlib.dll`.

I guess this has to do with the existence of the .NET Core framework and also the .NET Standard specification, but am unsure about how these three assemblies differ and on which platforms they can be found respectively.

So if my guessing is right, the question is: which assembly belongs to which Framework (.NET, .NET Core, .NET Standard) ?

Comment: You are right it is due to the existence of .NET Core and .NET Standard. Normally you don't have to take care on which one you should reference. It is automatically done when you create a .NET project (mscorlib.dll), a .NET Core project (System.Runtime.dll) or a .NET Standard project (netstandard.dll).

Comment: @TheGeneral It's a good question imo, why not asking it? Some people just want to know things, right? :p

Comment: @Sébastien Krejci if you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: MSDN only documents the *reference assemblies*, the ones you use to compile your program.  But they are not the ones where System.String actually lives, mscorlib.dll and System.Private.CoreLib.  This kind of [TypeForwardedTo] indirection helps to paper over the implementation differences, a good backgrounder [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/history/evolution-of-design-time-assemblies.md).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right it is due to the existence of .NET Core and .NET Standard. Normally you don't have to take care on which one you should reference. It is automatically done when you create a .NET project (mscorlib.dll), a .NET Core project (System.Runtime.dll) or a .NET Standard project (netstandard.dll).